# Which is the equivalent openssl commad to this c# signing code

Tags: c#, openssl, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I have the following code to sign a file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Disig.TimeStampClient;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ClientTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var certificate = GetCertificate("mycert.pfx", "password");
            var data = File.ReadAllBytes("data.bin");
            var signature = ComputeSignature(data, certificate);
            SavePemSignature(signature, "file-signature.pem");
        }

        static void SavePemSignature(byte[] signature, string filePath)
        {
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.Default))
            {

                writer.WriteLine("-----BEGIN CMS-----");
                var pos = 0;
                while (pos < base64.Length)
                {
                    var len = Math.Min(64, base64.Length - pos);
                    var line = base64.Substring(pos, len);
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                    pos += len;
                }
                writer.WriteLine("-----END CMS-----");
            }
        }



        static byte[] ComputeSignature(byte[] data, X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            if (certificate == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
            ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
            SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, true);
            CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, certificate);
            signer.DigestAlgorithm = System.Security.Cryptography.Oid.FromFriendlyName("SHA256", System.Security.Cryptography.OidGroup.HashAlgorithm);
            signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
            return signedCms.Encode();
        }

        static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string filePath, string password)
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            collection.Import(filePath, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
            var cert = collection.Cast<X509Certificate2>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PrivateKey != null && x.Extensions.OfType<X509KeyUsageExtension>().FirstOrDefault(c => (c.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature) == X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature) != null);
            return cert;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is the equivalent openssl command?

I tried the following, but I had not luck, the pem files are different:

```
openssl cms -in data.bin -sign -signer mycert.pem -md SHA256 -binary -noattr -outform pem -out file-signature.pem
```

Comment: I think this is your duplicate: [Different S/MIME signature between OpenSSL and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11526572/608639). This may apply as well: [OpenSSL S/MIME signature with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3931416/608639). If you are truly interested in the `openssl` command, then you should probably ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @jww. thanks, for pointing out my duplicate. if I include signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly; then the equivalent command is openssl smime -in data.bin -sign -signer mycert.pem -md SHA256 -binary -noattr -outform pem -out signature.pem

Comment: In signature generation you usually get things like date of signing and such. You should look for signature generation that is **compatible** with the **verification & validation** procedures. The signature doesn't need to be identical, it should be acceptable to the parties that should accept the result.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes. Yes I agree. I just was looking for an alternative way to sign a message, to be sure I'm signing the message properly. I need to sign an xml file and send it to a third party. The third party requires a PKCS7 signature included in the xml file. But the signature is not XML Signature Syntax. I'm having problems with the signature, so I thought I could tell them "hey, I'm signing the following way..." providing them the openssl command and the c# code I'm using.